# Teradata - Create views of tables in another database

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to create in Teradata VIEWS of tables in another database.
I have created both but now when making a select of the VIEW, It shows me the following Error: **"Table/View 'MyDatabase.MyView' not found, or you have no access rights"**.

What type of rights need the User, View, Table, Database... to make this works? And at what time and how should I give them?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to the document on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This doesn't look like a security error, so that's probably not the problem. Insure when you are referencing tables that you are fully qualifying them like `CREATE VIEW MyDatabase.myview SELECT * FROM someotherdb.someothertable`.

Comment: That seems to be a client application message rather than a database error message. For a user other than the creator to use a view referencing an object in another database, the "owner" (database containing the view) must have the relevant permission, `SELECT` in this case, `WITH GRANT OPTION` on the referenced object.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
@JNevill , I created the VIEWS with fully qualifying.

Comment: @Fred, I don't understand very well what you mean. My user have SELECT permission in both databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have *SomeDB.TableOrViewA* and a view *MyViews.ViewX* that references *SomeDB.TableOrViewA*. The "view owner" *MyViews* is allowed to provide access (via *ViewX*) only if *MyViews* holds corresponding rights `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

In order for a *UserN* (who is not the creator of *MyViews.ViewX*) to `SELECT` from the view, not only must *UserN* hold `SELECT` permission on *MyViews.ViewX* (or the entire *MyViews* database), but the *MyViews* **database** must also hold `SELECT WITH GRANT OPTION` permission on *SomeDB.TableOrViewA* or on the entire *SomeDB* database. This is true whether or not *UserN* has `SELECT` permission on the underlying *SomeDB.TableOrViewA* itself.

`GRANT SELECT ON SomeDB.TableOrViewA TO MyViews WITH GRANT OPTION;`

or `GRANT SELECT ON SomeDB TO MyViews WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Fred !
Now I understand what is the problem and I managed to solve it.